# Picturebox tick event behaving inconsistently

Tags: c#, forms, events, timer

So recently i have been trying to get into C# programming after spending alot of time in C.
Naturally i jumped right into learning a few new things, in this case i wanted to try some forms, classes and events - simple right?

Well apparently not, i am rather dumbfounded, i have been running the program, analyzing step by step, the tick event triggers as its supposed to, but the picture in the picturebox is not updated.

And here is the kicker, i made a button that runs almost identical code, and that works, what gives? i can barely get my head around it as it is.

http://pastebin.com/psYzQSLE - here is the code i am running currently.

And here is the specific segment of code i cant get to behave.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(swapper)
        {
            swapper = false;
            pictureBox1.Image = ima1;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            swapper = true;
            pictureBox1.Image = ima2;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Put all the _relevant_ code in the question by [Editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34937352/edit) it and write what your problem actually is.

Comment: Why is that swapper variable static?  I'm guessing you don't have the Load event wired up.  Just put that "Main" code inside your form's constructor.

Comment: @Mathemats, the OP did put the code he thought relevant... but I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks for the tip, i was messing around with the idea that maybe the bool got changed somehow without me knowing how, so i made it static for a moment there, that has been changed back. - and i moved the main code.
Just a little used to having a Main in C.

The entire code is in the link.

Comment: Your code, otherwise, as posted, works.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks alot Lars :) 
I have been having quite alot of trouble, thought this would be a very simple project.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and is working for me. I suspect the `Form1_Load` method is not hooked up to the form's `Loaded` event; you can check that in the designer.

Comment: There is a line in my designer that reads, nothing that says "loaded":

     `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);`

Comment: @Nodine, yes, I meant `Load` of course (the equivalent event in WPF is named `Loaded` so it got me confused...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out!
Being unfamilar with the design document, the timer was added to the tick in there and i also added it myself in my code, the result being a timer that triggers twice immediately, and thus i saw no result.

Problem is solved now, thanks for the warm welcome :)